# how to turn a long, script-like line into a single line?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to convert the below command to a single line, but to no avail. I've tried putting more apsas, braces, square brackets, but nothing.

```
$PBIFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:AllUsersProfile\Package Cache\" -Filter "PBIDesktopSetup_x64.exe" -Recurse
$PBISetup = $env:SystemDrive+$PBIFolder.PSParentPath.Split(':')[3]+"\PBIDesktopSetup_x64.exe"
Start-Process $PBISetup '/uninstall /quiet' -Wait
```

I tried this way but without success

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -noninteractive -command ($PBIFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:AllUsersProfile\Package Cache\" -Filter "PBIDesktopSetup_x64.exe" -Recurse; $PBISetup = $env:SystemDrive+$PBIFolder.PSParentPath.Split(':')[3]+"\PBIDesktopSetup_x64.exe"; Start-Process $PBISetup -Parameters '/uninstall /quiet' -Wait)
```

Comment: What makes you think one LOOOOOONG line of code is better than three readable lines?

Comment: Because I need to call these lines through powershell.exe -command as this will be entered in SCCM's "Uninstall" field

Comment: I feel that the process above is over complicated? please try: `Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:AllUsersProfile\Package Cache\" -Filter "PBIDesktopSetup_x64.exe" -Recurse | Foreach {Start-Process $_.FullName '/uninstall /quiet' -Wait }`

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot, but now it's calling that line with the "powershell.exe -noprofile -noninteractive -command" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an alternate approach I like to use when I have longer script that need to be executed inline without relying on an external script file.

Instead of trying to put everything on a single line, I use the `-EncodedCommand` argument of `Powershell.exe`. That way, there is never any issue since the encoded command is a Base 64 string representation of the script.

To get the proper call, you would need to convert the script into a Base64 string first. See how I wrapped your script.

```
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String(
[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes({
            $PBIFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:AllUsersProfile\Package Cache\" -Filter "PBIDesktopSetup_x64.exe" -Recurse
            $PBISetup = $env:SystemDrive + $PBIFolder.PSParentPath.Split(':')[3] + "\PBIDesktopSetup_x64.exe"
            Start-Process $PBISetup '/uninstall /quiet' -Wait
}))
```

The string we get from that is :

```
"CgAgACAAIAAgACAAIAAgACAAIAAgACAAIAAkAFAAQgBJAEYAbwBsAGQAZQByACAAPQAgAEcAZQB0AC0AQwBoAGkAbABkAEkAdABlAG0AIAAtAFAAYQB0AGgAIAAiACQAZQBuAHYAOgBBAGwAbABVAHMAZQByAHMAUAByAG8AZgBpAGwAZQBcAFAAYQBjAGsAYQBnAGUAIABDAGEAYwBoAGUAXAAiACAALQBGAGkAbAB0AGUAcgAgACIAUABCAEkARABlAHMAawB0AG8AcABTAGUAdAB1AHAAXwB4ADYANAAuAGUAeABlACIAIAAtAFIAZQBjAHUAcgBzAGUACgAgACAAIAAgACAAIAAgACAAIAAgACAAIAAkAFAAQgBJAFMAZQB0AHUAcAAgAD0AIAAkAGUAbgB2ADoAUwB5AHMAdABlAG0ARAByAGkAdgBlACAAKwAgACQAUABCAEkARgBvAGwAZABlAHIALgBQAFMAUABhAHIAZQBuAHQAUABhAHQAaAAuAFMAcABsAGkAdAAoACcAOgAnACkAWwAzAF0AIAArACAAIgBcAFAAQgBJAEQAZQBzAGsAdABvAHAAUwBlAHQAdQBwAF8AeAA2ADQALgBlAHgAZQAiAAoAIAAgACAAIAAgACAAIAAgACAAIAAgACAAUwB0AGEAcgB0AC0AUAByAG8AYwBlAHMAcwAgACQAUABCAEkAUwBlAHQAdQBwACAAJwAvAHUAbgBpAG4AcwB0AGEAbABsACAALwBxAHUAaQBlAHQAJwAgAC0AVwBhAGkAdAAKAA=="
```

From there, you can make your Powershell call but instead of the `-Command` argument, you use `-EncodedCommand`.

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -noninteractive -EncodedCommand "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"
```

Should you need to decode the command to edit it, you can do something like this (see below), then re-encode the modified script afterward and update your encoded command.

```
# $EncodedCommand need to be set to your base 64 string to be decoded.
$EncodedCommand = 'SABlAGwAbABvACAAVwBvAHIAbABkAA==' # Encoded "Hello World"
[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($EncodedCommand))
```

The advantage is that you don't loose readability since your editable version remains on multiple lines. You also avoid any parsing issues for more complex script.

Comment: I didn't know that, this is fantastic, really the powershell is almost a universe, that there are many unknown things hahahahaha, thank you very much!

Comment: I'm testing the decoding and the output is blank, is the command correct?

Comment: @AegisShimon Make sure that you set `$EncodedCommand` to your base 64 string first. If You use my snippet as is, it will be blank.

Comment: For instance `$EncodedCommand = 'SABlAGwAbABvACAAVwBvAHIAbABkAA=='` ... Then running the decode line will return `Hello World`. You do the same, except you put your encoded value instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-EncodedCommand` switch - it accepts a command/script as a base64 string, ideal for storing a single script as a command line argument:

```
powershell.exe -EncodedCommand <base64-encoded-script>
```

To encode a script:

```
# assign code to a variable
# in real life you would read this from the file with `Get-Content path\to\script.ps1 -Raw`
$rawCode = @'
$PBIFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:AllUsersProfile\Package Cache\" -Filter "PBIDesktopSetup_x64.exe" -Recurse
$PBISetup = $env:SystemDrive+$PBIFolder.PSParentPath.Split(':')[3]+"\PBIDesktopSetup_x64.exe"
Start-Process $PBISetup '/uninstall /quiet' -Wait
'@

# UTF16LE-encode the script
$utf16EncodedScript = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($rawCode)

# Base64-encode the resulting byte string
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($utf16EncodedScript)
```

The resulting command line then becomes:

```
powershell.exe -EncodedCommand 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
```

Comment: This really worked, this is fantastic, thank you very much!

Comment: This is nice!, wasn't aware you could encode the command!

Comment: What is the template for decoding?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 powershell.exe '-noprofile -noninteractive -command &($PBIFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:AllUsersProfile\Package Cache\" -Filter "PBIDesktopSetup_x64.exe" -Recurse; $PBISetup = $env:SystemDrive+$PBIFolder.PSParentPath.Split(':')[3]+"\PBIDesktopSetup_x64.exe"; Start-Process $PBISetup -Parameters '/uninstall /quiet' -Wait)'
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work mate.

Comment: For this approach replace the opening and closing parenthesis with single quotes, and then replace all internal single quotes with double quotes (or escape them). `-command '$PBIFolder ... -Wait'` but make sure you change `(':')` to `(":")` and `'/uninstall /quiet'` to `"/uninstall /quiet"`. I don't think that'll solve the OP's issue, but thought I would at least help correct the attempted answer.

Comment: No success, but encoding the code worked here, thanks a lot friend